# Animation on text using PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

*Rafael's interpretation of the question*

I want an animation in PowerPoint, where one word appears from left to right, as it is being typed, and then it disappears as it is being deleted with a backspace key, making room for a new word.

---

*Original post:*

I wanted to have some simple text animation like what is show on below website where I show one sentence and then in next animation few words in that sentence changes and then again it changes.

For ex.

First sentence

How many computers in your environment ?

and then in next animation computer word is replace by application and then in next animation application is repalce by users and i could see the word getting deleted and replaces with new word as shown in below website

See example below on this website

https://www.axonius.com/

Do we know how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry if the names on the options are not exact because I am using PowerPoint in Spanish. But I am posting some screen captures so you get the idea. Feel free to edit the post.

A general approach would be:

**I.** Prepare the design of your slide. Put a background and add a text block you want to animate.

**II.** Duplicate your slide.

**III.** On the first slide, on the animation panel (1) select your block of text and use "wipe" (2) as an entry animation.

**IV.** Go to effect options (3) and choose left to right (4)

[image]

Now on the second slide do the same with the block of text but choose right to left as the final step.

---

You can add both animations, entry, and exit on the same slide opening the animation panel, so you have things more organized using one text per slide instead of two.

[image]

---

The result

[image]

This makes a smooth transparent effect on the text.

---

Another variant, probably more exactly matching the look on your example is using the "Appear" (5) option and choosing character by character (7) on the options (6) of the animation:

[image]

The problem with this method is that the text will disappear left to right, not like using the backspace key.

[image]

Comment: Thank You So much Rafael. I think the second option is more closer to what i want. Only problem is that this animation doesnt work on a word in sentence. Animation is applied to entire sentence which i dont want. I want a particular word in sentence to removed and then replaces with another word as animation.

Comment: Split the text into two different blocks. Simple.